# How to pass a container as projected content in Angular

Tags: angular

Is there a way to pass a container or wrapper markup into a component as a projection content?

Here is some code:

**this is how I want to use it**

```
<my-component>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</my-component>
```

**the component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
        <ng-content select=".wrapper">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </ng-content>
    `
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

Comment: `<ng-content> element cannot have content`

Comment: I know. The code is just an illustration of the problem. I want to know if the is a way to overcome this limitation and achieve the desired result.

Comment: Have you tried using ng-template?

Comment: I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, 1+ years later, I finally know how to do this : )
You can pass a wrapper/container template to the component with `<ng-template />` and `ngTemplateOutlet`.

#### Component implementation

```
import { Component, ContentChild, Input, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'useful-generic',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="wrapper; context: {$implicit: body}"></ng-container>

    <ng-template #body>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #defaultWrapper let-content>
      <div class="default-wrapper">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class UsefulGenericComponent {
  @ContentChild('wrapper') wrapper: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('defaultWrapper') defaultWrapper: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (!this.wrapper) {
      this.wrapper = this.defaultWrapper;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Component usage

Example 1:

```
<useful-generic>
  <h1>Hello from inside default wrapper</h1>
</useful-generic>
```

Output 1:

```
<useful-generic>
  <div class="default-wrapper">
    <h1>Hello from inside default wrapper</h1>
  </div>
</useful-generic>
```

Example 2:

```
<useful-generic>
  <h1>Hello from inside my wrapper</h1>

  <ng-template #wrapper let-content>
    <div class="my-very-own-wrapper">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</useful-generic>
```

Output 2:

```
<useful-generic>
  <div class="my-very-own-wrapper">
    <h1>Hello from inside my wrapper</h1>
  </div>
</useful-generic>
```

#### Resources

1. [Live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-override-component-template-stackoverflow)
2. [NgTemplateOutlet (official docs)](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)